# Replacing from dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm building a program that is able to replace characters in a message with characters the user has entered into a dictionary. Some of the characters are given in a text file. So, to import them, I used this code:

```
    d = {}
    with open("dictionary.txt") as d:
        for line in d:
           (key, val) = line.split()
           d[str(key)] = val
```

It works well, except it adds "ï»¿" to the start of the dictionary. The array of to-be-replaced text is called 'words'. This is the code I have for that:

```
    for each in d:
           words = ";".join(words)
           words = words.replace(d[each],each)
           words = words.split(";")
           print words
```

When I hit F5, however, I get a load of gobbledook. Here's an example:
        \xef\xbb\xbf\xef\xbb\xbfA+/084&

I'm just a newbie at Python, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you create dictionary.txt? (And why did you use UTF-16?)

Comment: It seems you have an encoding problem, what's your `dictionary.txt` encoding? Was it done using Notepad? Also what does _gobbledook_ means? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure to save your file in dictionnary file in UTF-8.
With notepad++ (Windows) there are conversion functions if your former file is not utf-8.

The "ï»¿" pattern is related to latin-1 encoding (you won't have it if you use utf-8 encoding)

Then, instead of str(key), use key.encode("utf-8") to avoid possible other errors in the future.

If you want to know more, you can take a look to the good Python documentation about this : http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html